# Issue opening geomorph package

Tags: r, procrustes

Currently having issue opening geomorph in R. I recently updated R to the newest version. I also updated the packages "RRPP" and "rgl" after finding a thread from 2020 ([Geomorph not functioning after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62599795/geomorph-not-functioning-after-update)) where someone also had issues opening geomorph. I also recently went ahead and updated all old packages (not just the ones based off of the thread).

Computer info: I am using macOS Catalina version 10.15.7. Can't upgrade to the newest version for space reasons, but haven't had any issues using other packages in R (or running code in MATLAB).

R Version info:
RStudio 2022.02.0+443 "Prairie Trillium"

Mostly need geomorph for a GPA (procrustes analysis), but am open to other alternatives if I can't get geomorph to run. Currently it runs a never ending loop and then R terminates.

Appreciate any thoughts on what to do next or advice if you've run into this issue!

Thanks!

-KB

Update: there is a particular version of R on macs where it wouldn't run geomorph (after they updated). They waited to fix this with the next release of R, so there is a small gap in the geomorph package in which it won't run on a specific version of R for macs. I ended up uninstalling R and re-installing the latest version. This is a mac specific issue and if others come across this, updating to the newest version of R solved my issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. For visual/informational presentation of your session, probably better to provide `sessionInfo()` in place of your 'R Version info:' The 'how it works' shouldn't depend too much on updating to a higher OS version, but I'm not in mac. A 'never ending loop' suggests it is less the software than what it was 'told to do', and I'm uncertain where, elsewhere, you'd get reliable `procrustus` outside of `geomorph`. Perhaps it is more useful to provide; some data, some code attempted, and display the never ending loop, which, to it's credit isn't an error, one thinks. Welcome.

Comment: Hi there! I found elsewhere that a particular version of R on macs wouldn't run geomorph (after they updated). They waited to fix this with the next release of R, so there is a small gap in the geomorph package in which it won't run on a specific version of R for macs. I ended up uninstalling R and re-installing the latest version.